# Display Issues - Desktop larger than TV display

Tags: graphics, display, amd-graphics

I just migrated my HTPC from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 16.04. The install went fine however, at a resolution of 1280x720 or 1920x1080, the actual desktop is wider than the TV screen (primarily on the left and right sides, but  a little on the top and bottom also). This means I only see a very small portion of the toolbar on the left hand side (useful for launching applications!). Previously on Win7, the desktop fix perfectly on the screen at 1280x720 and 1920x1080.

One interesting fact is when I go to Ubuntu’s Control Panel -> Display Settings to change resolution and display settings, it seems to be detecting my display (a TV connected via HDMI) as a Samsung Electric Company 50”. I happen to have a Samsung 42” Plasma TV. Perhaps the EDID is being incorrectly read? I have been trying to test new modelines with xrandr and cdv, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help get this configured correctly?

Some background Info:

System Specs:

- Display: Samsung Plasma Display, HP-R4272
- Connection: HDMI MB: Asus M4A785-M w/ Integrated ATI Radeon HD4200
- Ubuntu: 16.04 Display
- Driver: radeon

From edit-read:

```
Section "Monitor"
Identifier "SAMSUNG PDP"
ModelName "SAMSUNG PDP"
VendorName "SAM"
# Monitor Manufactured week 50 of 2004
# EDID version 1.3
# Digital Display
DisplaySize 1110 620
Gamma 2.20
Option "DPMS" "false"
Horizsync 30-48
VertRefresh 55-65
# Maximum pixel clock is 80MHz

#Extension block found. Parsing...
Modeline "Mode 5" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
Modeline "Mode 0" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
Modeline "Mode 1" 74.25 1920 2008 2052 2200 540 542 547 562 +hsync +vsync interlace
Modeline "Mode 2" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
Modeline "Mode 3" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
Modeline "Mode 4" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 5"
```

From xrandr —verbose:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 720, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x51
Timestamp:  19274
Subpixel:   no subpixels
Clones:
CRTCs:      0 1
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
          filter:
scaling mode: None
supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
load detection: 1
range: (0, 1)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (0x54) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1102mm x 620mm
Identifier: 0x52
Timestamp:  19274
Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
Brightness: 1.0
Clones:
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0 1
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
          filter:
EDID:
00ffffffffffff004c2d8a0100000000
320e0103806f3e780aee91a3544c9926
0f505420000001010101010101010101
010101010101011d007251d01e206e28
55004e6c4200001e011d8018711c1620
582c25004e6c4200009e000000fd0037
411e3008000a202020202020000000fc
0053414d53554e47205044500a20011d
02031671438405032309070783010000
65030c0010008c0ad08a20e02d10103e
96004e6c420000180000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000003e
audio: auto
supported: off, on, auto
scaling mode: None
supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
dither: off
supported: off, on
underscan vborder: 0
range: (0, 128)
underscan hborder: 0
range: (0, 128)
underscan: off
supported: off, on, auto
coherent: 1
range: (0, 1)
  1280x720 (0x54) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x55) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x56) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1280x720 (0x57) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  720x480 (0x58) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x59) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x5a) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x5b) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

From ctv:

```
# 1280x768 59.87 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.78 kHz; pclk: 79.50 MHz
Modeline "1280x768_60.00"   79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

From gtf:

```
# 1280x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 80.14 MHz
Modeline "1280x768_60.00"  80.14  1280 1344 1480 1680  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```